# Where is the authentication (user/password check) in Jhipster with JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt, jhipster

If I use JHipster + JWT and log in with wrong data for the first time, I get an error message (this is correct, of course). Unfortunately, I can't find where the authentication(user/password check) takes place.

The client calls'api/authenticate' and lands in the JWT filter. jwt does not yet exist here. And so it goes on in the chain.There are now 12 spring filters, but unfortunately I haven't found the check in any of them.

The'DomainUserDetailsService','UserJWT-Controller' are not called.

Question: Does anyone know where the authentication happens?

Thanks for the answer in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done in the AuthenticationManager which is built in SecurityConfiguration.java and uses DomainUserDetailsService

This is called when sending a POST to /api/authenticate which is handled by UserJWTController

I suppose you only looked at GET on /api/authenticate in AccountResource.java which is used only for checking that user is authenticated with a token.

Comment: see comment.BTW.: I'm a fan of JHipster you do a great job

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I mean'UserJWTController' as POST. I found the problem why the UserJWTController controller is not called. This was because I chose my wrong password smaller than 4 characters. This made @Valid active and it never called my controller